# How do I use Clonezilla with a crossover cable to a Windows 7 machine?

Tags: clonezilla

I can't find a way (that I can do anyway) to use Clonezilla with a crossover cable.  My thought is it is much faster to clone from my desktop than across the network.

The server would be Windows 7, as it will house the actual Clonezilla compressed files.  Clonezilla, of course, is Linux.

Is it possible to use Clonezilla with a crossover cable?

Comment: Not sure but it should work the same way as over network, you need to set static IP on both server and client and let them in the same subnet and accessible to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For around 10 years or so, the need for a crossover cable has been eliminated by the prevalence of auto-MDIX in all modern NICs. So you can do this with a straight-through cable if both devices are relatively modern.

As Chris.C said, configure IP addresses on both devices so that they are in the same subnet and they will be able to communicate with each other. You may need to check firewall settings to allow this.